# Создание объекта ImageIcon на базе изображения, загруженного из файла

Tags: java, gif

Добрый вечер!
Я в Java новичек, поэтому многоне знаю.
Недавно разбираясь с библиотекой классво Swing прорабатывал код и натолкнулся на вот такой момент.

```
ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon("myIcon.gif");

    JLabel jlabicon = new JLabel(im);
```

Создается объект на базе изображения полученного из файла.
Хотелось бы поинтерисоваться, как получить это изображение и передать его в конструктор объекта ImageIcon.
Зарание благодарен.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. В данном случае указано имя файла, который должен находится в корневой директории проекта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я понял в чем мой недочет. Все оказалось намного проще чем я думал. НАдопросто добавить изображение в папку проекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кинь изображение в корень папки. Могу показать небольшой пример как я выводил изображение но оно у меня jpg.

Comment: Спасибо. За ответ. По не опытности не понял как нужно делать, думал что нужно создавать поток ввода-выводаю

Comment: Та не за что ) Сам только учусь так что тебя прекрастно понимаю